# Format question pages so Safari 5 can enter Reader mode

Tags: feature-request, safari

Safari 5 has been out for days and Stack Overflow still doesn't support its reader mode.

Why is that?

Comment: Wouldn't this require SO using HTML5 elements which some browsers won't support? Unless I misunderstand, Safari's reader works against `<article>` elements.

Comment: Some details on why it might not work at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2999600/how-to-disable-safari-reader-in-a-web-page (And really, how would Reader be better than the current layout?)

Comment: +1 Thanks for letting me know that Safari 5 is out!

Answer (score 2):

Given the importance of voting, I think the current layout suits the sites better.

Comment: Voting was fun for the first year, but I'm tired of expressing my opinion. The StackOverflow engine should have figured out what I like and dislike by now and do my voting for me.

Comment: @Frank A. Krueger: And get me a pony, too. Although SO looks like magic sometimes, it's still not AI, not by a long shot.

Answer (score 2):

Reader mode isn't something sites are supposed to actively support; if nothing else it's the other way round. [Read more](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65503/support-article-mode-on-the-kindle/65763#65763).